# How do I change the background color of a cell using WPFDatagrid based on databinded by DataTable

Tags: c#, wpf, datagridview, datagrid

I  have Data Table with around 66 columns and 4000 rows

each Row comes to some category of some conditionally based coloring

I am very new to WPF actually i have implemented some condition based coloring the rows in datagridview but WPF as component DATA GRID

How to achieve cell based coloring based on cell value ? in WPF

I am tried this example not able understand please provide some good example which binds data from datatable and coloring datagrid cell based on value

[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1745132/how-do-i-change-the-background-color-of-a-cell-using-wpf-toolkit-datagrid](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TVREV.png)

[image]

Comment: What is the condition?

Comment: for example : if (str == "SKIP")
                            {
                                cell.Style.BackColor = Color.Orange;
                            }

                            else if (str == "FAIL")
                            {
                                cell.Style.BackColor = Color.Red;
                            }

Answer (score 0):

Define the triggers to check the  str column values "skip","fail" and set the color of the background.

```
<DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding str}" >
  <DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
         <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="Text" Value="SKIP">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Orange"/>
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger Property="Text" Value="FAIL">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
     </Style>
  </DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
</DataGridTextColumn>
```

Comment: @Inqusitivemind .. this  triggers  not fits for my  problem .. Because my condition keep on changing based on first column value for example : if First column is 1C then i need to check for string from column number 10 - 20 if  those columns contains N/A{Yellow} or skip {Blue} or fail{Red} colur..

Comment: Please see this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36545435/wpf-datagrid-change-single-cell-background